# Matlab Circle Definition on Grids

Tags: matlab, grid, geometry

here is my question.

I have a dataset with x and y coordinates (point data). I have created an N x N matrix and I have divided the space into N x N grids. I put the counts of every grid cell into the corresponding matrix coordinate.

Now I would like to generate a circle in the N x N grid area. But since this is not real space but a grid space, I need to know which grid cells are on this circle. In other words, if my radius is 2 grid size then I want to have a list of the grids because I will get the total number of points using that grid counts.

I used moore neighborhood but Moore neighborhood is more of a rectangle. I am coding it in Matlab but any idea will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I need more clarification.  Do you want to generate a circle in each `N x N` square area?  Also, if this is what you want, then I don't understand what you mean by "which grid cells are on this circle".  Also, it will be difficult to generate a symmetric circle if the grid size isn't odd.  For example, if you had a `5 x 5 grid, you can easily place the centre of the circle at `(7,7)` and the circle would be symmetric.

Comment: My only concern is getting the counts around a grid. So if the circle will exceed the overall area it will not be able to get any count from outside. Suppose grid is my center and I have a specified radius which is defined by grid metric. So radius can be at most N/2 and min 1. Suppose we have a grid cell which is on (3,3) on a 10 X 10 grid. For example for radius 2, I need the coordinates of the cells around.